# sklearn TheilSenRegressor ValueError when setting fit_intercept=False for 1d regressors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to fit a line (1d feature) with 0 intercept using `sklearn.linear_model.TheilSenRegressor` but, when I specify `fit_intercept=False`, I get the following error:

> ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)

This is the original example in the `sklearn` manual which works fine also specifying `fit_intercept=False`:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import TheilSenRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, n_features=2, noise=4.0, random_state=0)
reg = TheilSenRegressor(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
reg.score(X, y)
```

Here is the original example modified for `n_features=1` which works with the default `fit_intercept=True`:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import TheilSenRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, n_features=1, noise=4.0, random_state=0)
reg = TheilSenRegressor(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
reg.score(X, y)
```

Here is the original example modified for `n_features=1` and `fit_intercept=False` which causes the failure:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import TheilSenRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, n_features=1, noise=4.0, random_state=0)
reg = TheilSenRegressor(random_state=0, fit_intercept=False).fit(X, y)
reg.score(X, y)
```

The failures occurs both when calculating the score or making a prediction.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

By checking the script `exmath.py` under `~/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py`, one gets to the following function

```
from scipy import linalg, sparse

def safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output=False):
    """Dot product that handle the sparse matrix case correctly

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array or sparse matrix
    b : array or sparse matrix
    dense_output : boolean, (default=False)
        When False, ``a`` and ``b`` both being sparse will yield sparse output.
        When True, output will always be a dense array.

    Returns
    -------
    dot_product : array or sparse matrix
        sparse if ``a`` and ``b`` are sparse and ``dense_output=False``.
    """
    if a.ndim > 2 or b.ndim > 2:
        if sparse.issparse(a):
            # sparse is always 2D. Implies b is 3D+
            # [i, j] @ [k, ..., l, m, n] -> [i, k, ..., l, n]
            b_ = np.rollaxis(b, -2)
            b_2d = b_.reshape((b.shape[-2], -1))
            ret = a @ b_2d
            ret = ret.reshape(a.shape[0], *b_.shape[1:])
        elif sparse.issparse(b):
            # sparse is always 2D. Implies a is 3D+
            # [k, ..., l, m] @ [i, j] -> [k, ..., l, j]
            a_2d = a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1])
            ret = a_2d @ b
            ret = ret.reshape(*a.shape[:-1], b.shape[1])
        else:
            ret = np.dot(a, b)
    else:
        ret = a @ b

    if (sparse.issparse(a) and sparse.issparse(b)
            and dense_output and hasattr(ret, "toarray")):
        return ret.toarray()
    return ret
```

Notice that it performs a dot product between two arrays. This function `safe_sparse_dot` is called under the hood when calling `reg.score()` with the parameters `X`, `self.coef_.T` (In your example, these are `X` and `reg.coef_.T`).

### The n case regressor variables with n >= 2

Now, **when you have two regressor variables** with `fit_intercept=False`. For example, the one you prior mentioned

```
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, n_features=2, noise=4.0, random_state=0)
reg = TheilSenRegressor(random_state=0, fit_intercept=False, verbose=True).fit(X, y)
reg.score(X, y)
```

you get the following shapes of your variables

```
X.shape
>>> (200, 2)
reg.coef_.T.shape
>>> (2,)
```

now if you call the sparse dot function, you'll get a result because (200,2) x (2,) is a valid multiplication.

```
safe_sparse_dot(X, reg.coef_.T)
>>> array([-3.11195300e+01,  3.97852518e+00,  3.83392622e+01,  6.10470897e+01,
          -4.93104975e+00, -7.79836353e+00, -2.92253822e+01,  1.95366691e+01,
          -2.53890049e+01,  2.31799242e+00, -4.29133706e+01, -2.64249217e+01,
          .....
          .....
```

### The single variable regressor case

**When you consider a single regressor variable**. For example,

```
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, n_features=1, noise=4.0, random_state=0)
reg = TheilSenRegressor(random_state=0, fit_intercept=False, verbose=True).fit(X, y)
reg.score(X, y)
```

you'll get the following error

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
```

mainly because `reg.coef_` is a scalar and should be reshaped to be a 1d array, that is, `reg.coef_.T.reshape(-1)`. Thus, the dot product operation can be called

```
safe_sparse_dot(X, reg.coef_.T.reshape(-1))
>>> array([-3.11195300e+01,  3.97852518e+00,  3.83392622e+01,  6.10470897e+01,
           -4.93104975e+00, -7.79836353e+00, -2.92253822e+01,  1.95366691e+01,
           -2.53890049e+01,  2.31799242e+00, -4.29133706e+01, -2.64249217e+01,
          ....
```

I don't know if this issue has already been raised, but you could issue one on the github page of scikit-learn.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I opened [ticket](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18104) about the issue.